# Are Spore crawlers detectors when unburrowed?

Tags: starcraft-2

I haven't taken notice yet, but while spine crawlers are unburrowed, do they still count as detectors? Or must they be burrowed?

Comment: lol, I think someone doesn't like me on here... always likes to downvote xD

Comment: I downvoted this one because it's an absurdly easy to answer question. I didn't know the answer either, I just googled it in about 6 seconds. Some of your other questions have been more interesting.

Comment: My thought in posting this question here, was for when others search for the same question, draw more users to this site.

Comment: Questions posted should be about actual problems you face. Arqade will never supplant a game specific wiki for things like this.

Comment: It was a true, real problem I faced. Others may have faced the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Liquipedia, [they only detect when burrowed](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Spore_Crawler):

> Take note that Spore Crawlers lose their detection ability while uprooted.